# Fixed width top-bar button

Tags: zurb-foundation

Is it possible to create fixed width button in top bar (with full height). I need sync `catalog button` with `categories list` from another row section.

```
 .top-bar
    .catalog-button
    ...
 .row
    .column3.sidebar
    .column9.maincontent
 // some elements omitted, just for illustration
```

`.catalog-button` should be above `.column3.sidebar` and have same width. (On first page catalog should be always open and have place in content section(column3), on other pages opens by hover and in content section content have all 12 columns width but dropdown should have the same view)

[image: Top-bar fixed button]

Answer (score 1):

Check this live example, tel what do you think : http://jsbin.com/razefe/1

```
<div class="medium-1 columns" id="sidebar">

    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li id="title" class="link-rightbar"><a href="#">Catalog</a></li>
        <li class="link-rightbar"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="link-rightbar"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li class="link-rightbar"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li class="link-rightbar"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>    

</div>
<div class="medium-11 columns" id="content">
      <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
        <ul class="title-area">
          <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
          </li>
           <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
          <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
          <!-- Right Nav Section -->
          <ul class="right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Left Nav Section -->
          <ul class="left">
            <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
          </ul>
        </section>
      </nav>

        <div class="content">
                <p>psum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo provident, fugiat reprehenderit, minima nihil odit, quo repudiandae quam magnam est consequatur laudantium voluptas vero excepturi eos a, laboriosam atque rerum?</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

And simple CSS

```
#title {
  height:45px;
  background: #6BC369;
}

.side-nav {
  padding:0px;
}

#sidebar {
  padding-right:0px;
}

#content {
  padding-left:0px;
}


.link-rightbar {
  margin: 0px !important;
}


.link-rightbar > a {
  color: black !important;
  padding: 16px 15px !important;
}
```